# How to attach particle system to point on sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system

I have a gameObject which is rotating around one point, and attached particle system (attached to child node) to it, and when I change direction of rotation (gameObject is moving opposite direction), my particle system doesn't flip with my gameObject and continue going on top (it should be on the bottom).

So I've spent much time on it, and maybe you have know some ways to fix that. Hope screens will make it more clear.

1st direction:

[image: 1]

2nd direction:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this in 2 ways:

1. flip the character by changing y rotation to -180 and then to 0 instead of doing it with other methods or animation. In this way the child object will move too and it will work.
2. change the render mode of the partcyle system to world space and see if it's moving. Or if you are changing the flip with the animation you can record the animation so you change the position of the particle system manually. In this way then you are going to flip the particle is going to flip for the animation

Comment: So im trying to implement 1st way something like this(code below) but it gives be strange result. 
(vec is changing point my gameObject is rotating around to opposite, flipShip() just flips sprite by y). 
I rly dont understand whats wrong with it. Actually if i change Z rotation by 180 in inspector it works properly

Comment: then try to change the Z with the script and it will move the Partycle too

Comment: yeah, thats what im trying to do (in my opinion), but it doesnt work as i want. Like it rather change rotation in some random way than by 180. In one method call it works properly, next one rotate by 90, next doesnt rotate at all. Idk why it happens

Comment: Should clarify that im talking now about my gameObject, particle is rotating well with ship as i wanted, but now ship doesnt flip haha

Comment: Just check in the inspector the rotation you need (x, y, z and the amount, 180) and then in the script if(buttonispressed) this.transform.Rotation = Quaternion.Euler(put 0 to the axis you don't want to rotate and -180 or 180 to the one right) for example thi.transform,Rotation =Quaternion.Euler(0,180,0) and then another if with the transform.rotation all to zero

Comment: Yep, but my ship is flying around another gameObject so, its rotation is changing between -90 and 270, but when i just add 180 it doesnt flip but behaves itself strange way like rotating every time different way

Comment: and the most strange is when i add 180 degrees threw inspector it works properly. So i cant understand whats wrong with my code

Comment: So ive fixed that by using transform.Rotate instead of transform.rotation. Anyway thx for your help

Comment: Yep, sorry it was my mistake. Transform.Rotate is better :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void changeDirection()
{
    flipShip();
    vec = new Vector3(0, 0, -vec.z);

    var rotationVector = new Vector3(transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, 
    180+transform.rotation.z);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationVector);
}
```